# How to Connect to MySQL database using Swift-Nio

Tags: mysql, swift, macos, cocoa, swift-nio

I used node js to connect mysql server and it is working good.  I used the API developed in node js and used in the local macOS app. The problem is querying the data from mysql database on workbench is fast but in node js API it is very delay. So, I've to connect mysql db directly from my macOS app.

I installed mysql from here: https://www.mysql.com/downloads/

Also I am using mysql work bench to test the connection and It is connecting without any problem. So, In system preference I've an mysql extensions to start and stop mysql server. In the extension I can see the root folder locate in `/usr/local/mysql`

I created new project and added swift package of [mysql-nio from here](https://github.com/vapor/mysql-nio)

In that repository their API document link is broken https://api.vapor.codes/mysql-nio/master/MySQLNIO/ But I found the correct link https://api.vapor.codes/mysql-nio/main/MySQLNIO/MySQLConnection/

By using that link, I tried to connect with below code,

```
//https://github.com/vapor/mysql-nio

import Cocoa
import MySQLNIO

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    
    private var group: EventLoopGroup = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 4)
     
    private var eventLoop: EventLoop {

        return self.group.next()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
        do{
            
            let socketAddress = try SocketAddress(ipAddress: "127.0.0.1", port: 3306)
            
            let logger = Logger(label: "MyLogger")
            let connection = MySQLConnection.connect(to: socketAddress, username: "root", database: "MyDB", password: "3$@sdRt34@sdf$dja2", tlsConfiguration: nil, serverHostname: nil, logger: logger, on: eventLoop)                
            connection.whenComplete { result in
                
                switch result{
                    
                case .success(let connection):
                    
                    print("Success! Status closed: \(connection.isClosed)")
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                     
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        NSApp.presentError(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }catch{
            
            NSApp.presentError(error)
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NIOCore.IOError error 1.)

I added `App Transport Security Settings` -> `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES` in the xcode project `info`

I don't know How to resolve this issue. Can you please help me to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying your code to test Swift-NIO and it's crashing out in try SocketAddress. It says to Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions. Any suggestions? (running Ventura)

Comment: oh, it also crashes with the  try .makeAddressResolvingHost() version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app sandbox, you'll need to enable "Outgoing connections (client)" and then it should work.

[image: outgoing connections]

Unfortunately, because of a [Swift bug](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/58724) the error printout of Swift errors isn't actually useful if you do `localizedDescription`. To see the actual error, you'd need to put something like a `print(error)` in your error handler.

See how in the screenshot below, the `print(error)` prints actually useful text like `connect(descriptor:addr:size:): Operation not permitted (errno: 1)` if I don't check the "Outgoing connections (client)"?

[image: XCode console]

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I completely forgot this.